# Object Info returns 0. Random materials for different objects

Tags: materials, node-editor

According to the blender documentation:

> The Object Info node gives information about the object instance. **This can be useful to give some variation to a single material assigned to multiple instances, either manually controlled through the object index, based on the object location, or randomized for each instance**. For example a Noise texture can give random colors or a Color ramp can give a range of colors to be randomly picked from.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/input/object_info.html

But how do you actually achieve the effect mentioned in the description? When I try randomize the texture for multiple objects the value of the location, object index or random output of the object info always returns 0.

[image: Node Setup]

Answer (score 2):

I found the mistake myself. The object info values are only applied once the scene gets rendered. Therefore I could not see any changes myself in the editor.